# Line by Line Sentiment Analysis?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am currently working on Sentiment Analysis on people pages from  WikiPedia.

I have downloaded a large set of  pages on people(like  Leonardo Da Vinci, Issac Newton, etc )  from  wikipedia and converted  them to text files (size of data set is 20000+  files).

My requirement  is to do Sentiment Analysis on every sentence   i.e. to have a sentiment  score on each sentence of every file and  aggregate the result of every  sentence to give an overall score for that  file.

I am currently  trying to understand on how MALLET works and see  if I could use MALLET  for this purpose?   Could  anyone  suggest any other tool that can do  this type of sentiment  analysis?  Also any guidelines on how to get  MALLET working for this  requirement would be a great help.

Please  Help. 
Thanks, Sam

Answer (score 2):

For simple off-the-shelf sentiment analysis, take a look at [Pattern](http://www.clips.ua.ac.be/pattern), a Python library developed at the University of Antwerp. It can return the polarity and subjectivity of English sentences in the following way:

```
from pattern.en import sentiment

your_sentence = "This is a great sentence."
(polarity, subjectivity) = sentiment(your_sentence)
```

Comment: nice link for Pattern, do you have used?

Comment: Yes, I've used it. It's not as accurate as training your own system, but it's a decent quick solution.

Comment: customizing by training data set makes any difference? well any other better sentiment lib if you know apart from common nlp libs?